# Rust no_std static lib panic_handler

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

I want to build a no_std static library with rust.
I got the following:

```
[package]
name = "nostdlb"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
```

lib.rs:

```
#![no_std]

pub fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}
```

Despite setting the panic behaviour for both dev and release to `abort` cargo gives the following error:

```
error: `#[panic_handler]` function required, but not found

error: could not compile `nostdlb` due to previous error
```

I thought the panic handler is only required when there is no stack unwinding provided by std?

Comment: The panic handler is also responsible for printing the panic message, which the default handler won't be able to do without std.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to write your own one. If you need just aborting, consider using the following one:

```
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

I also highly recommend to unmangle the function and use C calling convention if you’re going to use this symbol somewhere (not import it the library as a crate, but link it manually):

```
#[no_mangle]
extern fn add(right: usize, left: usize) -> usize {
   right + left
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! btw. One also has to add the `eh_personality` language item.

Comment: @curunir, it's not supposed to require an `eh_personality` of your target or cargo.toml declare aborting on panic. You can make a dummy function though

```
#[lang = "eh_personality"]
fn ep() {}
```

This will generate one or two dummy symbols in binary. Not the best option, but definitely not the worst.

Comment: Strangely enough I had panic = "abort" on both the release and dev profile but it kept complaining.